# Can a bit bitwise shift expression1 << expression2 with different types hurt performance?

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I wonder if you can lose some performance by using different types like this:

```
unsigned int nr0 = 8;
unsigned char nrBitsToShift = 2; //unsigned char, ok?

nr0 <<= nrBitsToShift;
```

instead of this:

```
unsigned int nr0 = 8;
unsigned int nrBitsToShift = 2;

nr0 <<= nrBitsToShift;
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Tye type of the second parameter doesn't matter so long as it is an integer . The compiler will just send it directly to the shift assembly instruction

Comment: You have the code... give it a try and find out :) Run it a few hundred thousand times each and see what happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, this all depends on your CPU hardware.

A typical, modern CPU will have a CPU instruction to shift a value by the given number of bits. One CPU register gets loaded with a value to shift, a second register gets loaded with the number of bits to shift. This is followed by an actual CPU instruction to execute the shift.

A typical 32 or a 64 bit CPU will have individual CPU registers that are 32 or 64 bits in size, but will have different instructions that use either the full width of the register, or just a portion of it. Just the lowest 8, 16, or 32 bits of each register, perhaps with an option for interpreting the lowest 8/16/32 bit value as either a signed or an unsigned value, where it matters.

Given this background information, let's revisit the code in question:

```
unsigned int nr0 = 8;
unsigned char nrBitsToShift = 2; //unsigned char, ok?

nr0 <<= nrBitsToShift;
```

It goes without saying that we're going to ignore the obvious optimizations that a modern compiler will perform here. A modern compiler will probably evaluate this sequence of code at compilation time. But let's ignore that, let's say that this is translated to machine code literally.

In that case, if the CPU in question has a left shift CPU instruction that specifies the number of bits to shift in the lowest 8 bits of a register, then the left shift operation gets translation to machine code directly, pretty much. But it's possible that the only left shift CPU instruction uses the full 16, 32, or maybe 64 bits of a CPU register, for the number of bits to shift. In that case, additional CPU instructions must be executed to extend the 8 bit value to 16, 32, or 64 bits.

This is, of course, a mostly theoretical discussion. For a practical answer, try compiling some test code, with all compiler optimization disabled, and benchmark it. I would actually doubt that a significant difference in performance will be observed. With modern hardware, the bottleneck will typically be RAM or I/O bandwidth. Modern CPUs have trouble executing enough instructions to keep themselves busy, before they're starved for I/O bandwidth.

And if you actually do manage to measure some difference in performance, it would apply only to the particular hardware you executed your benchmark on, for the reasons given above.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I had my suspicions that it was due to the CPU and its registers, thank you for your detailed explanation. I did some benchmarking with all the compiler optimizations disabled and the results was almost the same on my CPU.